# Java ClassLoader format for defineClass with directories/packages?

Tags: java, class, find, classloader

So I am writing a custom `ClassLoader` to find classes in jars, but I can't find the right format for the `defineClass()` parameter "name". I've tried `"d", "d.class", "a/b/c/d", "a.b.c.d"` and probably a few others. Here is my Exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: d (wrong name: a/b/c/d)

Does anyone know the proper way to format this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spearator is dot (.) and not slash (/) for path. So format of a.b.c.d should work if you are giving the right path.